# No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem to a known managed provider native type with dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net

Error occurs when I execute with following parameter

```
hobj.Add("@ItemPublisher", ddlPublisher.SelectedItem);
```

I've tried `SelectedItem`, `SelectedValue` and `SelectedIndex`, but it didn't work. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Remove "@" from your Field Name and use Value at the place of SelectedItem.

```
hobj.Add("ItemPublisher", ddlPublisher.Value);
```